# afnetworking downloading an array of images

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to download an array of images, but I never receive the image callback:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.apartments.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"downloading another image");
        ATProperty *aProp = self.apartments[i];
        if (aProp.aptImages.count > 0) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:aProp.aptImages[0]];
            NSLog(@"url string: %@", aProp.aptImages[0]);
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading_apt.png"];
            UIImageView *anotherImage;

            NSLog(@"about to start req");
            [anotherImage setImageWithURLRequest:request
                                placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
             {
                 NSLog(@"got an IMAGE ");
                 self.imagesArray[i] = image;
                 if (self.apartments[0] == aProp) [self setupDraggableView:image];
             } failure:nil];
        } else {
            UIImage *defImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_apt.png"];
            if (self.apartments[0] == aProp) [self setupDraggableView:defImage];
            [self.imagesArray addObject:defImage];
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I don't actually want to set an imageview, I just want to put the UIImage into an array for later use. In this case, the "got an IMAGE" log statement is never received. Why would this be the case? The url is valid. Also, is this somewhat like a javascript closure? For example if I have a total of 5 apartments in the array, when I do the first callout (i = 0) and get the success callback will i be the value in which the callout was instantiated (i.e. 1)?

Comment: Why are you using AF's UIImageView category just to download an image, if you don't want to set it to the image view? Wouldn't it be simpler to just use the NSURLConnection/Session apis to download it?

Comment: I don't know... Would it be?

Comment: Well, yeah. It does provide you with a cache system, but it also inflates the image by default, so that it'll be ready to be presented on the image view, so you're doing a lot of work that you don't necessarily want to be doing at this time. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m and http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFImageResponseSerializer.html for more. You also allocate an UIImageView that you'll be discarding and while it's not exactly expensive, it's still a lot of extra work that could be spared.

Comment: do you have an example of this?

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<#imageURL#>]];
        UIImage *downloadedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Do stuff
        });
    });

Would just download the image and then you can do your work on the main thread after the image is downloaded. You might want to use your own dispatch queue, though, so that GCD doesnt spawn dozens of threads for you, if you're doing lots of work.

Answer (score 0):

anotherImage is `nil`, so it never loads. try like that:

```
UIImageView *anotherImage = UIImageView.new;
```